# How do you copy+paste text from the terminal to a web browser and vice versa?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, copy-paste

I was just wondering if there's a simple way to do this, or whether it's completely dependent on the terminal you use. If that's the case, then is there a standard that most terminals go by?

Right now I'm using Ubuntu and I *assume* that I have GNOME terminal.

Answer (score 2):

In X11, you have two "clipboard" equivalents:

2. The **'CLIBPBOARD' selection** – like the Windows clipboard.

   To copy, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> if in GNOME Terminal, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> elsewhere.

   To paste in GNOME Terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>; in other programs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
3. The **'PRIMARY' selection** – somewhat more temporary, text-only.

   Simply select text to copy.

   Middle-click the mouse to paste. (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> usually works to paste, *except* in Firefox, sadly.)

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux terminals copy the text simply by marking it. To paste it, just go to the web browser's URL bar and middle-click to paste.

Sometimes it might be the right mouse button, and it should always work with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

From memory, the keyboard shortcuts should work, CTRL+C CTRL+V between the two. However in some shell environments, if you copy the text from a web browser then click both left and right buttons on your mouse (or middle mouse button) it will be pasted into the terminal window.

Also copying text from the terminal, simply highlighting the text in most cases copies the text to the clipboard.

Comment: Issuing `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` in the shell will not work as copy-paste by default. By default `Ctrl+C` sends the `SIGINT` signal to the shell and `Ctrl+V` interprets input escape character sequences.